# how to access parent v-data-table from template in nested v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a page made with vue using vuetify. It displays a v-data-table which can be expanded to reveal another v-data-table, like this:

```
      <div class="subsection">
        <v-data-table
          :headers="prescriptionHeaders"
          :items="pendingItems"
          show-expand
          item-key="id"
        >
          <template v-slot:expanded-item="{headers,item}">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">
              <v-data-table
                :headers="pendingPrestationHeaders"
                :items="item.prestations"
                v-model="selected"
              >
                <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
                  <div class="table-row-actions">
                    <v-tooltip left v-if="item.categeoryTypeId === 6">
                      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-icon
                          v-bind="attrs"
                          v-on="on"
                          @click="func1(item)"
                          class="action-doc"
                        >
                          mdi-file-document-outline
                        </v-icon>
                      </template>
                      <span>blablabla</span>
                    </v-tooltip>
                  </div>
                </template>

              </v-data-table>
            </td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </div>
```

the problem is that I need to call func1 with a property of the item from the outer v-data-table. How can I access it from within my `` <template v-slot:[`item.actions`] `` template ? I know I could include a reference to the parent item in my child item, or just duplicate the data that I need from the parent into the child (that's what I'm currently doing), but I was just curious to find out whether there is a way to refer to the "outer" item in the template slot, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

To access the item of the outer v-data-table, you need to change the inner data table with props.item
Something like this should work.

```
   <template v-slot:[`props.item.actions`]="{ props.item }">
      <div class="table-row-actions">
        <v-tooltip left v-if="props.item.categeoryTypeId === 6">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-icon
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
              @click="func1(item)"
              class="action-doc"
            >
              mdi-file-document-outline
            </v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>blablabla</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly the same challenge. I want to access to item ID of the outer v-data-table from the inner one. The paragraph shows the data correctly. How to access this value from the inner data-table?

```
<template v-slot:expanded-item="{ item }">
        <td :colspan="attachmentHeaders.length">
          <p>{{item.finDocId}}</p>
          <v-data-table
            :headers="attachmentHeaders"
            :items="item.attachmentPlainDtos"
            item-key="finDocId"
            disable-pagination
            :hide-default-footer="true"
            no-data-text='Geen bijlagen'
          >
            <template v-slot:[`item.attachmentActions`]="{ item }">
              <v-icon large @click="removeAttachment(item.id, item.attachmentId)">
                mdi-delete
              </v-icon>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
        </td>            
      </template>
```

Comment: for my use case, in the end I added the data I needed from my the items in my `pendingItems` array to the items in the  `pendingItems.prestations`. e.g. if pendingItems contained data like this:
`{
  id: number;
  data1: string;
  data2: string;
}`

and it's the data2 I needed in my inner table, then the data from the inner table now looks like this:
`{
  id: number;
  prestationData1: string;
  prestationData2: string;
  data2: string; // from parent object
}`

and so I could use that data2. It's a bit silly to duplicate the data but I didn't find any other ways back then.